# How to repeat this function

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

I have this function and I need it to repeat from the start once it reaches the end.

```
processSlider: function() {
    function a() {
        var c = document.querySelector(".layout-process-slider .process-point.active");
        if (!c.nextElementSibling) {
            $(".layout-process-slider .process-point").first().trigger("click")
        } else {
            $(".layout-process-slider .process-point.active").next().trigger("click")
        }
    }
    if ($(".layout-process-slider").length) {
        var b = setInterval(a, 2500)
    }
    $(".layout-process-slider .process-point").click(function(d) {
        var c = $(this).data("select");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".items").children().removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.item-info[data-item="' + c + '"]').addClass("active");
        if (d.originalEvent !== undefined) {
            window.clearInterval(b)
        }
    })
}
```

**How can I get this to loop once it reaches the end?**

Comment: When using recursion remember to maintain a condition to finish your execution, otherwise you'll surely end hanging your browser

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you want to use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) for this.

Give your function a name and make it call itself whenever it reaches the end.

```
function f() {
 // ...
 f(); // <-- recurse
}
```

So in your case, something like this would work:

```
processSlider: function processSlider() {
  //                    ^ give it a name (doesn't have to be the same as the property to the left)
  // ...
  processSlider(); // <-- recurse
}
```

An important caveat is to make sure you have a **recursion base case** that will stop the function from running indefinitely (unless you actually want it to run forever).

```
processSlider: function processSlider() {
  // ...

  if (! /* whatever your base case is */) {
    processSlider(); // <-- recurse only if base case is false
  }
}
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` when using your example.

Comment: @jarmerson because you don't have a recursion base case. You need some logic to determine when to stop running the recursion.

Comment: Here's the page I'm working on - https://sites.btwebnetwork.com/compliancemate/compliancemate/#child-75

Comment: Here's the page I'm working off of which has the same slider and same code - but it loops in this instance. I can't figure out what the difference is in my code :( https://www.compliancemate.com/compliancemate